# Do I need to install a package (openSWAN or strongSWAN maybe) to use ipsec?

Tags: ipsec

I want to connect to a windows share that only accepts ipsec transport mode. I have a list of security policies and a shared secret. I've skimmed through the man page on ipsec.conf on the web and it seems to be the place to put these polices. If ipsec is part of the kernel (and I think it is, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04) do I need to install some other package in order to get this working? I'm guessing it's either openSWAN or strongSWAN but don't know the difference.

Answer (score -1):

Did you see this [Article](http://www.pariahzero.net/Blog/files/e7d5abf84a96640d5cd70dd0dfb3d200-71.html).It might help you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...